# Any dictionary application capable to look up for misspelled words?

Tags: windows, dictionary

I am looking for an English-English dictionary capable of finding words that are the most similar to the word entered by the user (given that they can be different by several deleted and inserted characters).

Both free and commercial software is ok. Under 100$.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example, do you care about language, OS, pricing?

Comment: @Nick Wilde, language? What do you mean? Interface language? 99.9% of software supports English anyway.

Comment: If I did have data I  would argue about 99.9% of software - I would with no basis on any sort of data estimate probably in the 85% range. I was meaning what language(s) at minimum should the dictionary be for (whatever the interface); just because I don't like presuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If a web-app is acceptable**

[MerriamWebster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) will do fairly well on that. *One caveat; if it is already a real word but not the word you want it won't give suggestions*. It is free, however there is no offline or self-hosted option. They do have iOS and Android app versions but I haven't used them so don't know for certain whether they have the similar word feature.

An example would be say I was meaning to lookup hmm [eldritch](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eldritch) and input instead [eldrach](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eldrach) (a instead of i, deleted t) it would suggest:

```
Aldrich
eldritch
Delaroche
Heydrich
oligarch
dreich
Dirac
dyarchy
El Dorado
electric
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I need... but it's the best answer so far.